R table with values of all rows and columns
I have a long table and want to have a long table with the sum of each column and each row and total sum.



AUX
Century
n




launch
19
500


launch
20
500


launch
21
500


throw
21
500


launch
16
153


throw
20
125


launch
15
101


launch
17
95


pull
21
81


throw
19
55


toss
17
47


launch
18
40


toss
19
38


launch
13
32


toss
21
28


toss
16
20


toss
18
16


launch
14
15


toss
20
11


pull
18
8


pull
20
7


shoot
17
3


shoot
21
3


pull
15
2


shoot
19
1


shoot
20
20



I used this code:
wide.verb.century <- verb.century.counts |> 
  group_by(AUX) |> 
  tidyr::spread(Century, n)

And got this wide table



AUX
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21




toss
NA
NA
NA
20
47
16
38
11
28


shoot
NA
NA
NA
NA
3
NA
1
1
3


launch
32
15
101
153
95
40
500
500
500


throw
NA
NA
NA
NA
NA

55
125
500


pull
NA
NA
2
NA
NA
8
NA
7
81



Question1: How can I change NA to 0 (zero)? I tried this code, but got an error message.
wide.verb.century <- verb.century.counts |> 
   group_by(AUX) |> 
   summarise(n = sum(n, na.rm = TRUE)) |> 
   tidyr::spread(Century, n)

Question2: How can I add a row at the bottom and a column at the right end that each sum the values of all rows and columns, respectively?
Desired output:



AUX
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
Total




toss
0
0
0
20
47
16
38
11
28
160


shoot
0
0
0
0
3
0
1
1
3
8


launch
32
15
101
153
95
40
500
500
500
1936


throw
0
0
0
0
0

55
125
500
680


pull
0
0
2
0
0
8
0
7
81
98


Total
32
15
103
173
145
64
594
644
1112
2882



Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

spread has fill argument, set it to fill = 0.

Q2: addmargins(as.matrix(wide.verb.century[,-1]))

@Edward I did this and got an error message
wide.verb.century <- verb.century.counts |>    group_by(AUX) |>    tidyr::spread(Century, n, fill = 0) |>    addmargins(as.matrix(wide.verb.century[,-1]))

Don’t use pipe.

@Edward Thank you! Got it now! I'm a newbie :)

Onw way to solve your problem:
addmargins(xtabs(n ~ AUX + Century, df)) 

        Century
AUX        13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21  Sum
  launch   32   15  101  153   95   40  500  500  500 1936
  pull      0    0    2    0    0    8    0    7   81   98
  shoot     0    0    0    0    3    0    1   20    3   27
  throw     0    0    0    0    0    0   55  125  500  680
  toss      0    0    0   20   47   16   38   11   28  160
  Sum      32   15  103  173  145   64  594  663 1112 2901

In case you would like the output to be a data.frame/tibble instead of a table object, then use
addmargins(xtabs(n ~ AUX + Century, df)) |> 
  unclass() |> 
  as_tibble(rownames="AUX")

# A tibble: 6 × 11
  AUX     `13`  `14`  `15`  `16`  `17`  `18`  `19`  `20`  `21`   Sum
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 launch    32    15   101   153    95    40   500   500   500  1936
2 pull       0     0     2     0     0     8     0     7    81    98
3 shoot      0     0     0     0     3     0     1    20     3    27
4 throw      0     0     0     0     0     0    55   125   500   680
5 toss       0     0     0    20    47    16    38    11    28   160
6 Sum       32    15   103   173   145    64   594   663  1112  2901

